# How to center-align a custom SVG icon in a Material-UI IconButton

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, material-ui, icons

I'm trying to produce an icon button that looks like this:
[image]

So far what I've got is this:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import { SvgIcon, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

import {ReactComponent as homemadePlayIcon} from "./play-icon.svg"

<IconButton onClick={this.playIconButtonClick} disableRipple={true} style={{color: "rgb(0,0,0,0)", width: '35px', height: '35px', backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', boxShadow: "3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"}}>

    <SvgIcon component={homemadePlayIcon} />

</IconButton>
```

How do I center-align the icon inside the icon button?

Thank you,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the desired result by using [@svgr](https://react-svgr.com/) with the --icon option (to preserve the viewbox property of the SVG) and by including the generated component inside the IconButton as follows:

```
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

import PlayIcon from "./icons/PlayIcon.js"

<IconButton onClick={this.playIconButtonClick} disableRipple={true} style={{color: "rgb(0,0,0,0)", width: '35px', height: '35px', backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', boxShadow: "3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"}}>
    <PlayIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit that with this:

```
<IconButton onClick={this.playIconButtonClick} disableRipple={true} style={{color: "rgb(0,0,0,0)", width: '35px', height: '35px', backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', boxShadow: "3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work, but unfortunately it didn’t have the desired effect. Instead, it affected the alignment of the component in relation to other components, putting it on a different row from them.